# Unable to create new page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When i try to create new page in WordPress, the page doesn't created,

But after Disable all plugins that i installed in my WordPress, then try to create page the Pages are created normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a most likely a JavaScript conflict with 2 plugins.
What you can do is disable all plugin and enable them one at a time, testing the page creation functionality.

Once you have isolated the offending plugin you can write the authors and tell them about the conflict, or try to hunt down the issue yourself.